# Time data type not working when creating a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to create a table and one of the columns is of the data type time. But whenever I run it to create the table, it gives me an error and I know the error is caused by something to deal with the time data type. What is the problem?

```
CREATE TABLE Departures (Airline varchar(30), DepartureTime time(5), Gate int);
```

The error says: [Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 42X01] Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 65.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did. It's sql.

Comment: The create atble runs with myql 8 without a problem and so i think you have another problem, that comes not from that query